# Android - layout on low resolution

Tags: android, user-interface

On the big screen layaut looks great, but with a little big problem resolution.  Controls on each other, text is behind them. Layout uses weight, and must adapt itself. What i can wrong?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDCGs.jpg

This is one line. Other is similar.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Понедельник"
        android:id="@+id/textViewMonday1"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="@dimen/schedule_font_size"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp" />

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editTextMonday1"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="08:30"
        android:entries="@array/hours"/>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="time"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editTextMonday2"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:text="22:00"
        android:entries="@array/hours"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Выходной"
        android:id="@+id/checkBoxMonday"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="@dimen/schedule_font_size" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

put android:layout_weightSum="4" in the linear layout and use  android:layout_weight="1" in each component

Comment: Dont work. Elements do not scale below a certain limit